# Adding javascript to shopify's checkout success page

Tags: shopify

I need to create an app which adds some javascript upon a successful order checkout. How do I achieve this?

I've checked the docs and template files but it seems like a method to inject code like this doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [ScriptTag](http://api.shopify.com/scripttag.html) to accomplish this. To quote from the docs:

> Note that a ScriptTag will only appear in checkout if the src starts with 'https://' in order not to break the SSL lock.